# Finding Jordan form for $n\times n$ matrix satisfying $M^2= - I$

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

> Determine the Jordan form (over $\mathbb{C}$) of nxn matrices $M$ satisfying $M^2=-I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix.

The minimal polynomial divides $x^2+1$, so I would like to conclude that the minimal polynomial is either $x+i$ or $x-i$, but is it possible $x-i,x+i$ are not the minimal polynomial? I see that $x^2+1=0$ implies one of $x\pm i=0$ because $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is an integral domain, but matrices with multiplication don't form an integral domain. So isn't it possible that $(M+iI)(M-iI)=0$ while neither $M\pm iI=0$? One can easily construct 2x2 nonzero matrices whose product is zero.

Comment: For instance, $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ has minimal polynomial $x^2+1$, and not $x+i$ or $x-i$.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The minimal polynomial must be one of the *three* polynomials $x^2+1$, $x+i$, $x-i$. Note that a $2\times 2$ example for the first case is rotation by $\pi/2$ counterclockwise.

Comment: The Jordan forms are any Jordan forms composed of Jordan blocks whose eigenvalues are $\pm i$.

Answer (score 1):

You can't conclude that the minimal polynomial is either $x+i$ or $x-i$.  For instance, your matrix could be $\begin{pmatrix}i & 0\\ 0 & -i\end{pmatrix}$.  Indeed, *any* monic polynomial can be the minimal polynomial of a matrix; a general way to do this is to take the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix).

So if you want to find the Jordan forms by thinking about the minimal polynomial, you will have three different cases: the minimal polynomial is $x-i$, the minimal polynomial is $x+i$, and the minimal polynomial is $x^2+1$.  (Actually, there is a fourth case: the minimal polynomial is $1$.  This case is only possible for $n=0$, though.)  But the easiest way to solve this problem is not to think about minimal polynomials at all.  Instead, just suppose you have a matrix in Jordan form such that $M^2=-I$.  Then each Jordan block of $M$ also satisfies $M^2=-I$.  When does a Jordan block square to $-I$?

Comment: I don't think the minimal polynomial can be $1$ since the characteristic polynomial divides some power of the minimal polynomial.

Comment: @cap: Well, the characteristic polynomial could be $1$.  But this is only possible for $0\times 0$ matrices.

Comment: I wonder where and why are $\;0\times0\;$ matrices treated...